# jQuery Datepicker age validation function returning undefined error

Tags: jquery, function, validation, datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker on a sign up form and am trying to validate a minimum age of 16.
I have used https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Date-of-Birth-Age-validation-with-jQuery-DatePicker.aspx as a reference point.

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 mt-3 col-md-6 mt-md-0">
    <label for="dateBirth" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="dateBirth" name="dateBirth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#dateBirth').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1920:+0',
        onSelect: function (dateString, dateBirth) {
            ValidateDOB(dateString);
        }
    });
});
function ValidateDOB(dateString) {
    console.log(dateString);
    var parts = dateString.split("/");
    console.log(parts);
    var dtDOB = new Date(parts[1] + "/" + parts[0] + "/" + parts[2]);
    var dtCurrent = new Date();
    if (dtCurrent.getFullYear() - dtDOB.getFullYear() < 16) {
        return false;
    }
 
    if (dtCurrent.getFullYear() - dtDOB.getFullYear() == 16) {
 
        if (dtCurrent.getMonth() < dtDOB.getMonth()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (dtCurrent.getMonth() == dtDOB.getMonth()) {
            if (dtCurrent.getDate() < dtDOB.getDate()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Validation

```
if(!ValidateDOB()) {
    error.style.display = "block";
    error.innerHTML = 'You must be at least 16 years of age to register as a panellist.';
    dateBirth.classList.add("is-invalid");
    return;
}
```

When I select a date, in my console it is outputting the date (i.e. `15/02/2023`) as well as the `parts` variable (i.e. `["15", "02", "2023"]`) however when I submit the form to run the form validation, I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dateString.split')`.

This would usually suggest to me that dateString is not returning anything, however the console log is proving it is. What could be wrong here?

Comment: You are calling `if(!ValidateDOB())` without any arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did away with the function and just split all the dates up in to parts, so run some validation by year, then by month if the year is equalled, then by day if the month is also equalled. Not the cleanest of solutions but it works well.

```
    var today = new Date();
    var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
    var todayMonth = today.getMonth()+1;
    var todayDate = today.getDate();

    var dobParts = dateBirth.value.split("/");
    var dtDOB = new Date(dobParts[1] + "/" + dobParts[0] + "/" + dobParts[2]);
    var dobYear = dtDOB.getFullYear();
    var dobMonth = dtDOB.getMonth()+1;
    var dobDate = dtDOB.getDate();

    var age = 'valid';
    if(todayYear - dobYear < 16) {
        var age = 'invalid';
    }
    if(todayYear - dobYear == 16) {
        if(todayMonth < dobMonth) {
            var age = 'invalid';
        }
        if(todayMonth == dobMonth) {
            if(todayDate < dobDate) {
                var age = 'invalid';
            }
        }
    }

if(age == 'invalid') { // if date of birth is less that 16 years ago today
    error.style.display = "block";
    error.innerHTML = 'You must be at least 16 years of age to register as a panellist.';
    dateBirth.classList.add("is-invalid");
    return;
}
```

Comment: The error is because the dateString is defined within the onSelect function of the datepicker and is not available in the global scope. To resolve this, you need to store the selected date string in a global variable. please check my modification

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the validation part of your code, **ValidateDOB()** is called without passing any argument. In the **ValidateDOB** function definition, dateString is expected as an argument.

You should pass the selected date string to **ValidateDOB** function in the validation part of the code like this:

```
var selectedDate;

$(function() {
    $('#dateBirth').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1920:+0',
        onSelect: function (dateString, dateBirth) {
            selectedDate = dateString;
        }
    });
});

if (!ValidateDOB(selectedDate)) {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then got an error that dateString was an unknown variable

Comment: @Adrian The error is because the dateString is defined within the onSelect function of the datepicker and is not available in the global scope.
To resolve this, you need to store the selected date string in a global variable. please check my modification